# Accessing the calendar with android sdk

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to access the calendar with the API from the sdk, but the APP is crushing every time I try to access. Is there some kind of protection in android that prevent APP's from accessing the calendar?

I`m trying to accomplish something like this app

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.samcom.nexty&feature=search_result

Comment: No you should be able to access the calendar. Where is the debug error pointing to?

Comment: Please use the Google Calendar GData API to access the user's Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct permissions for accessing the calendar?  I believe you may need to declare this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
//If you need to write to the calendar
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```